# Asp.Net- Create single object and use it on many aspx.cs pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on an Asp.Net c# project. In this project I am using an object such as MyObject obj=new MyObject() on many aspx.cs pages.
Is there any way so that I could just create a single object and use this object on any number of aspx.cs pages.
Any help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create `Class` and Add this in Your `App_code` folder in `asp.net`

Then You can Access This Class in code behind by

**EDIT:**

What you required it is called as `Singleton Pattern`

> ```
>  Singleton s = Singleton.GetInstance;
> ```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
///


//Lazy Initalization
public  class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new Singleton();

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
//Early Initalization
public class Singleton
{
private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();
private Singleton() { }

public static Singleton GetInstance
{
get
{
return instance;
}
}
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: actully that is not question which I asked. I wants to know if there is a way that I can create a SINGLE object of a class and then I can use that particular SINGLE object any where in my project.

Comment: I mean Global object in simple term.

Comment: @user1301587 so you want something like `if instance exists then return that instance or create new instance and reutrn`

Comment: @Ganesh..Yes perfect I think that make sense. Can you please explain how I can achieve it?

Comment: @user1301587 Updated anwer

Comment: nice to help you, to find the name of it :P

Comment: Personally I would prefer a method called `GetInstance()` or just the property name `Instance` - "get get instance" sounds a bit off to me.

Comment: I am not sure whether singleton will work for me or not. Because my applcation is going to be access by many users on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is called singleton (pattern, there are many explanations of it just google it, if you don't know it).
You can do this in ASP.NET, if you use static variables, because those are used in every user session on the server.

If your program runs on different servers (like its possible in Sharepoint), it won't work. The only work around, that comes to my mind is to use an out-of-process session state (like SQLServer or Stateserver). But thats not a good way.

Comment: Yes, I think your suggestion is spot on. Thanks a lot.